# Inconsistent integration from mathematica and hand

Tags: integration

$\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{x}{2}e^{imx} \, dx$ by hands give $\frac{\pi}{im}$ assume m is not zero.

But in mathematica: I type:

`Integrate[((x/2))*Exp[I*m*x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]`

gives

`(-1 + E^(2 I m \[Pi]) (1 - 2 I m \[Pi]))/(2 m^2)`

Which is this:

[image]

How did i go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is an integer, it holds that $e^{2im\pi}=1$, so
$$
\frac{-1+e^{2im\pi}(1-2im\pi)}{2m^2}=-\frac{i\pi}{m}=\frac{\pi}{im}.
$$